# read linux config files using java

Tags: java, file, properties, config

I need some help in my project a build application in Java that reads config files from a Linux system. I want to show some value from these files like this:

```
//the code in config file
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.128 192.168.1.254;  
option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address        192.168.1.255;#comment here
....
}
```

In the application, it should be print something like this:

```
  network 1 : 192.168.1.0/24
  range : from 192.168.1.128 to 192.168.1.254
  mask : 255.255.255.0
  broadcast : 192.168.1.255
```

So I need to read the value from specified args like "option subnet-mask" to the end of the line is ";" and return just the value "255.255.255.0".
and if there is a comment "#", don't do anything just go to next line.
Each configuration starts from "{" and ends at  "}". So when it comes to "}" it should stop and go for the next network if there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to open the file in Java. You can do so using InputStreamReader or other input readers. Read the lines and use Java regular expression package to match the patterns you are looking for. This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) will help with the pattern matching.

Comment: i do something like that

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the issue is then? Or what you've tried that is not working? Thank you

Comment: i do loob to read liens and test if the line conteant the word like subnet but when i go to next word  <blink> while (sc.hasNextLine()) {   String line = sc.nextLine(); if(line.contains("subnet")) { String ss = sc.next(); System.out.println(ss);}} </blink>

Comment: Do something like this:

Comment: Sorry, for the previous comment:
Look at this [page] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html). If the line contains a keyword (subnet for example), create a pattern that looks for strings you are search (ip addresses format) and call match, which will give you the indices of where your matches occur, from theere you can get the substrings and print them. I thought Java provided a method similar to python re.find(), but it doesn't; that would have been simpler for your case.

Comment: thanks is more than helpful. now is just i need to print from where the first match start to the end match which is ";"